# GitHub fork one repository to multiple identical copies

Tags: git, github, repository, git-fork

I will need to fork an upstream repository on GitHub to my own account as multiple copies/repositories.
E.g. the original repository to be forked: "https://github.com/{UPSTREAM}/{REPO}"
The multiple forked repositories will be like:

1. https://github.com/{MY_ACCOUNT}/{REPO}_1"
2. https://github.com/{MY_ACCOUNT}/{REPO}_2"
3. https://github.com/{MY_ACCOUNT}/{REPO}_3"
4. https://github.com/{MY_ACCOUNT}/{REPO}_4"

But I don't seem to be able to fork the same original repository multiple times on GitHub. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

That's right you can't fork a repo twice. What should it be goog for to have two identical copies? You can fork repo A to B, got to B and are still unable to fork it - identical copy ... -, change something in B, now you can fork it to C etc.

But you'll probably demur that the content of A, B and C is now different. Thats right.

So you can only clone the repo localy, reinitialize it and push it several times to previous created repositories.

But what shall this be good for?

Comment: The reason I need to have multiple repositories that should be cloned from the same old repository on GitHub is that Heroku requires a URL to the individual GitHub repositories to deploy those multiple apps on it.

Comment: Yes, I see.
So was the answer helpfull to you?